# How can I access the scanner functionality of my Samsung CLX 3175N over the network?

Tags: networking, samsung, scanner

I have a Samsung CLX 3175N network capable color laser printer/scanner which was sold as being Linux compatible. Whereas the printer undeed works in the network.

It has been impossible up to now to get the scanner working under Ubuntu (safe for using Windows XP running in Virtualbox on the Ubuntu client), but that is not my understanding of Linux compatibility.

Is there anybody who knows a method to access a network Scanner in Ubuntu?

Comment: found this [answer][1]. Worked for me.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115864/how-to-make-samsung-clx-3185-scanner-part-work

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with this script, on the older Samsung all-in-one, CLX-2160N, and apparently it also works on the CLX-3160N

http://www.jon.demon.co.uk/dell1600n-net-scan/

I have a little wrapper script that passes my usual preferences to the script, so I can just run "./scan" at a terminal

The procedure is

- Run the script in --listen mode with the correct parameters
- Walk up to the printer and use the menu to select network scan

  - Select your options
- Scan your image

The script should have written files to the folder you specify in the --scan-dir option.

While this is nowhere near as simple as "Simple Scan", I scan infrequently enough that I'll put up with a little fiddling.

Comment: tried with my clx3185fn - doesn't work...