# how to make Samsung CLX-3185 scanner-part work?

Tags: samsung, scanner

I have the Samsung CLX-3185 printer/scanner. The printer-part works fine using 3175 drivers found by (Xubuntu/XFCE) printer setup wizard. However it does not seem to recognize the scanner part. Xsane does not find the scanner. Is there a setup HOWTO for this anywhere that I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Instructions how to set-up samsung CLX-3185FW**.

Source: [baltas125@ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11680651&postcount=13). Originally taken from:  [bchemnet](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html).

From the 1st link:

After executing instructions I have successfully installed CLX-3185FW over the network. It prints and scans over the network. I have made it on Ubuntu 11.10, 32bit.

Before installing you MUST REMOVE any other previously installed drivers for Samsung.

Step 1 (edit sources):

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add lines:

```
#samsung drivers
deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra
```

Step 2 (install authentication key) :

```
wget -O - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Step 3 (update sources):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 4 (install packages):

Open ubuntu software center and install one by one all packaged that start with `samsungmfp-`, excepting:

- first install packages which do not have the word "legacy";
- do not install packages which offer you to remove any other packages;
- Do not install `samsungmfp-parallel` it should only be installed if your printer is actually connected via a parallel port;

Step 5a (check if you are in lp group). Run in Terminal:

```
cat /etc/group | grep lp
```

If your account name is next to lp, everything is ok, else add yourself to lp group, e.g. execute Step 5b.

Step 5b (add yourself into lp group if needed):

```
sudo usermod -a -G lp USERNAME
```

(more information about groups [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/10/...iric-ocelot-2/))

That's it! Now you can search for your printer in network and add it as clx-3180 series and it will work.

P.S. Previously I have made some changes to some files. But I do not know if it has any impact. If you have executed the five step above and still no luck, try making those changes:

```
/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
```

lines added

```
#Samsung CLX-3170fn & CLX-3175FW
usb 0x04e8 0x342a
```

In ...

```
/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
```

lines added:

```
#Samsung CLX-3185FW
usb 0x04e8 0x343d
```

In ...

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

lines added:

```
# Samsung CLX-3185FW
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="343d", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Answer (score 3):

here's some feedback:

- I installed the Unified Linux Driver provided by Samsung ([german manual](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Samsung-Laserdrucker#Installation-CLX-3170-als-Netzwerkdrucker-und-Netzwerk-Scanner) providing useful links. The Samsung site has problems atm...). That made the printer work, but not the scanner
- I hadn't installed xsane then, so I did `sudo apt-get install xsane`. xsane didn't find the scanner
- I modified xerox_mfp.conf and 40-libsane.rules as described above, it should also work with the vendor and product ID of other mfp's you find using `lsusb`.

now the mfp works fine. thank you for the solution(s)!

btw: I'm with a CLX-3185 -> no netdiscovery required.

Answer (score 2):

I had the "Samsung Unified Linux Driver" and "Xsane" installed already and the printer worked well. Only the scanner was not found. After adding following entry in `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` the scanner was found:

```
#Samsung CLX-3180
tcp 10.0.0.11 # <- insert your printer's actual IP here
```

PS: I got that hint from [this link](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Samsung-Laserdrucker#Installation-CLX-3170-als-Netzwerkdrucker-und-Netzwerk-Scanner).

Comment: In the link you provided it says: "the IP address of course is just an example and should be replaced with the correct address". Instead of this you used "tcp 10.0.0.11". Please correct your answer.

Comment: ZeroConf/Avahi hostname instead of IP works, too. Even without the Samsung driver and `xsane`, `sane-backends*` was enough.

Answer (score 0):

The model number **Samsung CLX-3185**.

**Method 1:**

You may refer to the below links and use the troubleshooters. Check if it lists and helps resolve any issues: Open the Printer troubleshooter:

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/

**Method 2:**

You may check if you have the latest drivers installed for the device. You may refer to the below link for getting the latest drivers and check.

[Samsung CLX-3185 Driver](http://www.samsungdrivers.net/samsung-clx-3185-driver/)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your second link for Method 2 doesn't link to any Linux drivers so isn't really relevant to Ubuntu, you may want to post a different link.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is great installer in Samsungs website.

Use [this installer](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_HK_EN&CttFileID=6283513&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=CLX-3305W&VPath=DR/201510/20151027115542328/uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz) and everything works OK!

Verify that you have permission to the same group as well and after change please logout!

Answer (score -2):

You don't need all that stuff. Add the repo, then:

```
apt-get update
```

And install these 2 packages:

```
sudo apt-get install samsungmfp-scanner samsungmfp-netdiscovery
```

That's all you need.. at least for Ubuntu 12.04 that is all you need. I successfully printed a test page and scanned a document.

Comment: What repo do yo mean?

Comment: Ok, I have figured out that you likely mean this one: http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/. How trusted is it? I am not inclined to install some random person provided binaries.